# Locating an element on a page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate an element on a page and am having trouble. Not sure if frames/iframes are the issue. I have tried xpath and other locate criteria but i keep getting No such element message. Here is the webpage (http://www.ghin.com/lookup.aspx)

As i said, i have tried locating with xpath, css_name and other criteria.
Here is the relevant section of the HTML (had to remove the leading/trailing <> characters to make is visible (not sure why)

```
<td class="ClubGridHandicapIndex" style="width: 118px;" valign="middle" align="center">13.8</td>
```

I want to be able to scrape the value in that element (13.8 in the example shown)

Here is the xpath I get for this element (using firefox):

```
/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]
```

Here is the CSS selector i get:
.ClubGridSelectedRow > td:nth-child(2)

Here is the code i have tried (old attempts are commented out):

```
br.switch_to.frame(br.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
br.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_bodyMP_grdClubs"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]')
br.find_element_by_class("/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
```

`handicap_element = br.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_bodyMP_grdClubs > tbody > tr.ClubGridSelectedRow > td.ClubGridHandicapIndex")`

```
handicap_detail = br.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[1]/d1iv[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")

handicap_detail = br.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='ClubGridHandicapIndex']")

handicap_detail = br.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_bodyMP_grdClubs > tbody > tr.ClubGridSelectedRow > td.ClubGridHandicapIndex")
```

Any and all ideas are appreciated

I should be able to locate the element easily. I have used selenium quite a bit on another project with great success. However there is something about the HTML on this site that i am not familiar with.

Thanks in advance for assistance.

Comment: use code blocks for code in the future. its the {} button in the editor

Answer (score 0):

the following should work

`content = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ClubGridHandicapIndex')`

`content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td.ClubGridHandicapIndex')`

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: I tried both and get a no such element unable to locate element message. I don't really understand HTML well, but think it has something to do with a frame/window/iframe.